# JDK11 Exception; The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12, TLS11]

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I am getting below error while connecting target from one of the cloud platform PCF. The same rest call is working fine from soapUI and postman.When do we get this error exactly?

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected
>   protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13,
>   TLS12, TLS11]